# Flash player: usage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flash

I use Adobe flash player in my site, and now I need to increment some filed in the database when a user clicks on the player.
here is the script

```
<div id="conteiner" style="text-align: center;" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var s1 = new SWFObject("player.swf","ply","420","380","9","#FFFFFF");
            s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
            s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
            s1.addParam("flashvars","file=<?=$video ?>");
            s1.write("conteiner");
        </script>
```

I decided to use AJAX for it, but how can I write a function in the flash object?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
I only have the swfobject.js file, which contains such data

```
if(typeof deconcept=="undefined"){var deconcept=new Object();}
if(typeof deconcept.util=="undefined"){deconcept.util=new Object();}
if(typeof deconcept.SWFObjectUtil=="undefined"){deconcept.SWFObjectUtil=new Object();}deconcept.SWFObject=function(_1,id,w,h,_5,c,_7,_8,_9,_a){if(!document.getElementById){return;}this.DETECT_KEY=_a?_a:"detectflash";this.skipDetect=deconcept.util.getRequestParameter(this.DETECT_KEY);this.params=new Object();this.variables=new Object();this.attributes=new Array();if(_1){this.setAttribute("swf",_1);}if(id){this.setAttribute("id",id);}if(w){this.setAttribute("width",w);}if(h){this.setAttribute("height",h);}if(_5){this.setAttribute("version",new deconcept.PlayerVersion(_5.toString().split(".")));}this.installedVer=deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.getPlayerVersion();if(!window.opera&&document.all&&this.installedVer.major>7)
...
```

and the `player.swf`, and the HTML, I've shown already. I don't know is this flash player or no, and what can I do?

Comment: Where did player.swf come from?  Do you have the source?  You'll need to modify it to send a request to the server to update the database.

Comment: you're pretty much out of luck.  If you don't have the original source for player.swf, you can't change it.  Technically you can use a decompiler and then make changes and recompile, but if you don't have source you probably don't have rights either.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts in HTML don't get to listen to clicks in plugins. If you want to be informed of a click in a Flash embed, you will have to add code to the Flash movie to pass notification of the click back up to JavaScript.

What video player are you using? It might already offer this feature — check its docs. If not you'll need the source code to alter and recompile.

Comment: @bobince  SWFObject v1.5: http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/, but i don't understand it at all:(

Comment: @Syom SWFObject is not a video player. It is merely a javascript library that helps you to load flash files.

Comment: We've seen the update, the question remains: what is `player.swf`? It is that, the Flash file, that needs to support click interaction. SWFObject is of no interest.