# Clicks on a Flash / Silverlight object under a HTML overlay

Tags: javascript, html, flash, silverlight

is it possible to let clicks on a HTML element that's overlaying a Flash or Silverlight object bubble through to the Flash / Silverlight object? I've been experimenting with this, but i can't figure out if it is even possible because of possible security restrictions to prevent clickjacking.

I don't have access to the source code to the FL / SL object, so i can't implement an ExternalInterface or something like that.

Comment: Are you asking for Clickjacking as a feature?

Comment: Not without co-operation from the Flash code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639966/flash-player-usage/

Comment: Yeah, call it clickjacking if you want :) The problem is that i need to overlay a button on a Silverlight object for which i don't have access to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight you can have an HTML overlay, catch the Javascript Click Events, use the DOM bridge to let the app know about the mouse click, and use the [VisualTreeHelper.FindElementInHostCoordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.findelementsinhostcoordinates(VS.95).aspx) to figure out which element was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Any page click can be transferred to a Flash movie using the ExternalInterface class. You can use Javascript to call exposed methods in the Flash movie, and vice versa.

Don't know about Silverlight.